# How to fix python regex if statement?

Tags: python, pandas, regex, if-statement

I'm trying to find certain phrases in a data frame. These are the combinations of words I would like to find:

```
   apples
   bananas
   oranges
   apples and bananas
   apples and oranges
   bananas and oranges
   apples, bananas, and oranges
```

However, my code is not working for the cases where there are only 2 matching words. For instance, if the a row contains `'apple, banana, and orange'` my code will only output `'apple and banana'`

This is my code:

```
for i in copy.loc[fruits]:
    print(i)

    #if match apple
    if re.match(r'((?=.*apple)|(?=.*apples))',i):
        
        #if says no apple     
        if re.match(r'(\bno\b)',i) :
            print('no apples, only banana and oranges')
            print('')
        
        #if has apple and orange
        elif re.match(r'(?=.*orange)|(?=.*\boranges\b)',i):
            print('apples and oranges')
            print('')  
        
        #if has apple and banana
        elif re.match(r'(?=.*banana)|(?=.*bananas)',i):
            print('apples and bananas')
            print('') 

        #has apple, banana, and orange 
        elif re.match(r'(?=.*banana)|(?=.*bananas)(?=.*orange)|(?=.*\boranges\b)',i):
            print('apples, bananas, and oranges')
            print('')
       
       #has only apple
       else:
            print('apples')
            print('')
   
    #only oranges
    elif re.match(r'(?=.*orange)|(?=.*\boranges\b)',i):
       print('oranges')
       print('')  
        
    #only banana     
    else:
       print('bananas')
       print('')
```

My code does not work when there are only 2 matching words. How can I fix this?

Thank you for taking the time to read and help out. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Your code has mismatched parentheses. Please fix them.

Comment: Also, your text uses singular forms, whereas you have both plural and singular in your code. Why is that? What is the intention?

Comment: @InSync my apologies, I fixed the parenthesis. Some words in the data frame are plural, which is why I included both singular and plural. I just want to find how many instances of each word or phrase appear, regardless if they are singular or plural

Comment: `elif re.match(r'(?=.*banana)|(?=.*bananas)(?=.*orange)|(?=.*\boranges\b)',i):
            print('apple and bananas')`
            there is mistake in this print statement u should change it to `print('apple, oranges and bananas')`

Comment: @ shorttriptomars it happens! take care next time

Comment: @U-33 will do, thank you. I am still getting errors. Do you have any additional suggestions?

Comment: `'(?=.*banana)|(?=.*bananas)(?=.*orange)|(?=.*\boranges\b)` means: there is `banana` OR (there is `bananas` and `orange`) OR there is `oranges`. Based on your comments I assume this is not what you wanted.

Comment: Also, you can include both singe and plural in the following way: `(?=.*\boranges?\b)`

Comment: @markalex you're right.  thank you so much for taking the time to help me! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the order of the comparisons in your code.

```
row = 'apple, banana, and orange'

if re.match(r'(?=.*\bbananas?\b)', row):
    print('apples and bananas')
elif re.match(r'(?=.*\bbananas?\b)(?=.*\boranges?\b)', row):
    print('apples, bananas, and oranges')
```

```
apples and bananas
```

`elif` is "else if" - so if bananas matches, the `elif` code is not executed.

If you have patterns that are a "subset" of other patterns, you have to check the longer patterns first:

```
if re.match(r'(?=.*\bbananas?\b)(?=.*\boranges?\b)', row):
    print('apples, bananas, and oranges')
elif re.match(r'(?=.*\bbananas?\b)', row):
    print('apples and bananas')
```

```
apples, bananas, and oranges
```

Comment: you were right, thank you so much for taking the time to help me! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Apart from that you have to move the more specific match higher in the if else matching, you don't need all those lookarounds. You can just match them as well.

For a construction like this `((?=.*apple)|(?=.*apples))` you don't need any lookarounds. This would be the same as matching `\bapples?\b` where the `s` char is optional.

Also using [re.match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) matches from the start of the string, so matching `\bno\b` (which you can also write as `no\b`) does not really mean that you have matched `no apples` but matching `no` at the start of the string.

You can only be sure about that if all the strings have the same format.

This also applies to the last else where you print bananas, but you have not really matched bananas.

If you want to find the first location of a match in the string can make use of [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) instead.

You could make for example the code a bit more specific:

```
for i in copy.loc[fruits]:
    print(i)

    if re.search(r'\bapples?\b', i):

        if re.search(r'(\bno apples?\b)', i):
            print('no apples, only banana and oranges')
            print('')

        elif re.match(r'(?=.*\bbananas?\b).*\boranges?\b', i):
            print('apples, bananas, and oranges')
            print('')

        elif re.search(r'\boranges?\b', i):
            print('apples and oranges')
            print('')

        elif re.search(r'\bbananas?\b', i):
            print('apples and bananas')
            print('')
        else:
            print('apples')
            print('')

    elif re.search(r'\boranges?\b', i):
        print('oranges')
        print('')

    elif re.search(r'\bbananas?\b', i):
        print('bananas')
        print('')
    else:
        print("other..")
        print('')
```